# How can i convert an Integer to String in Visual Basic working with Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hi everyone i have the next doubt, i´m working with windows form in visual basic doing a CRUD. I have the next issue:

I have a textbox that receives an integer and when I try to register a user if I put a very high value (eg: 1,000,000) it gives me an error and only lets me register if I put a very low value (eg: 1,000), the error occurs when I try to save the information of the product to register specifically in the cell where I assign the value of the product, so I need to know if I have to Parse it and how to do that, here is the code, thanks

```
Private Sub btnRegistrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrar.Click

        Try
            obj.Insertar(txtDescripcion.Text, (CDate(dateFechaIn.Text)), (CInt(txtValor.Text)), txtStockMin.Text, txtCodBod.Text)
            dgListado.DataSource = obj.ListarEmpleados
            MsgBox("Se registro el articulo: " + txtDescripcion.Text)

            txtDescripcion.Text = ""
            dateFechaIn.Value = DateTime.Now
            txtValor.Text = ""
            lblCodigo.Text = "E00"
            txtStockMin.Text = ""
            txtCodBod.Text = ""

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("Error al registrar articulo")

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: What's the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: The [Integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/integer-data-type) data type can go from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, so the problem is somewhere else. Or you really are entering a value that is bigger than that upper limit. Show us your CODE and/or the actual value you are typing in....

Comment: Hi dude! the error happens when I press the button to register in the windows form window and it returns the message that I put in the exception

Comment: this is the code, I couldn't order it I hope you understand @Idle_Mind

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73912215/edit) your question to include the code you just added in comments (click that link or click Edit below your question).  And when I say "what is the exact error" I mean the exact exception message, not the error presented to the user in the catch.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to the community, I already edited the message thanks for your time @squillman

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for adding the code to the question, but you forgot to add the excact exception message you get.

Comment: I tried changing the exception message to MsgBox(ex.Message) and it tells me:

the arithmetic operation has caused an overflow @squillman

Comment: What is `obj.Insertar()`?

Comment: is a function of the main class that helps me save the information

Comment: Get rid of the `Try/Catch` so that you can see EXACTLY where the exception is occurring.

Comment: Or instead of getting rid of it, go to the Debug menu, open the Exceptions window, and change every CLR exception to break-on-throw (by default, most of them only break if unhandled).  As a general rule, this makes debugging easier, and if you have a "noisy" program, you can selectively turn off individual exceptions (even sometimes by throw location).

Comment: Your title says that you want to convert an `Integer` to a `String` but your question indicates that you're converting a `String` to an `Integer`.

Comment: For user input, instead of using `CInt` it would be better to use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) before using the value. Always try to program so that exceptions aren't raised if you can.